Calculating numbers that require greater than 16 byte data type in C++
I'm working on a function to calculate Fibonacci numbers and return the lowest value digit of that number in C++. I've found that in C++, the largest data type is __uint128_t, which gives me 16 bytes to work with. I wrote an overload to handle streaming __uint128_t. This will calculate up to the 186th Fibonacci number and then overflow at 187. I need to go much higher than 186. This is my function:
__uint128_t get_fibonacci_last_digit_fast (int n)
{
    __uint128_t f[n];

    f[0] = 0;
    f[1] = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i < n + 1; i++)
    {
        f[i] = f[i - 1] + f[i -2];
    }

    return f[n] % 10;
}

I am aware of boost library and other libraries that assist with handling large data in C++, but this function is for an assignment that has to be submitted to an auto grader which doesn't have these libraries installed. There is only the standard C++ libraries, so my code doesn't compile when submitted with these libraries. I'm considering possibly building a data type to handling this issue. Any direction and assistance with proceeding forward will be greatly appreciated.

Small note: you're using a VLA (variable length array) which is not part of standard C++.

"The Fibonacci sequence is the series of numbers where each number is the sum of the two preceding numbers." -- maybe I'm wrong on this, but this feels like you don't need the full numbers: you don't really care about the higher digits...

If your concern is only unit digit, you might apply modulo on each f[i]. And you no longer need "big" type.

Why are you calculating the entire number if you only want the last digit?  Just use an ordinary int, and trim away all but the last digit at each step, e.g. f[i] = (f[i-1] + f[i-2]) % 10;  You'll be doing a lot more % operations, but integer precision will no longer be an issue.

Accessing f[n] is not valid which is done twice (last iteration of loop and in return statement).

Also, there’s no need for an array here; all you need is the last two values. sum = f0 + f1; f0 = f1; f1 = sum;.

There is only the standard C++ libraries -- However be aware that the auto grader seems to accept non-standard C++ types such as __uint128_t and non-standard C++ syntax such as __uint128_t f[n].  So your auto-grader isn't as C++ standard as you believe.

"I've found that in C++, the largest data type is __uint128_t," -- You should change "in C++" to "in the C++ implementation I'm using" (and maybe identify your compiler/toolchain), since __uint128_t is not standard C++. (The double underscore implies this.) Standard C++ only guarantees at least 8-byte integers (long long).

In standard C++, the largest integral types (long long, unsigned long long and (C++11 and later) fixed-width types such as std::uint64_t, std::uint_least64_t ) are only guaranteed to be 64 bits.  (They may be larger, but the sizes are implementation-defined, and there is no guarantee of any integral type being larger than 64 bits).   Rather than trying to find a (non-standard) larger type, I suggest you work with a standard container of a standard type (e.g. std::vector<unsigned long long>) and implement operations you need in a way that doesn't rely on size of the integral type.

No "return the result modulo some number" exercise is supposed to be solved by just applying % to the result of a trivial solution. The point of this exercise is usually that you learn (or remember) that (a + b) % m == ((a % m) + (b % m)) % m, so you only need one digit of every number in the series; realizing that you don't need to store more than the two most recent numbers; and discovering that the last digit is periodic.

If you only need the last digit, you can use the Pisano period:
#include <iostream>

int get_last_digit(unsigned long long n)
{
    n %= 60;

    if (n <= 1)
        return n;

    int prev = 0;
    int curr = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        int next = (prev + curr) % 10;
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
    }

    return curr;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long long n = 10000000000008989ULL;
    std::cout << get_last_digit(n) << "\n";
}


Prints
9
Notes:

The Pisano period for % 10 is 60. We can manually list the Fibonacci sequence modulo 10 until we see a repeat of the initial 0, 1 pattern:


0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 3, 1, 4, 5, 9, 4, 3, 7, 0, 7, 7, 4, 1, 5, 6, 1,
7, 8, 5, 3, 8, 1, 9, 0, 9, 9, 8, 7, 5, 2, 7, 9, 6, 5, 1, 6, 7, 3, 0,
3, 3, 6, 9, 5, 4, 9, 3, 2, 5, 7, 2, 9, 1, ..., 0, 1


The sequence 0, 1 repeats after 60 numbers. Therefore, we can use a precomputed array to efficiently get the last digit for n modulo 60 in O(1) time complexity:

#include <iostream>

int get_last_digit(unsigned long long n)
{
    const int pisano[60] = {
        0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 3, 1, 4, 5, 9, 4, 3, 7, 0, 7, 7, 4, 1,
        5, 6, 1, 7, 8, 5, 3, 8, 1, 9, 0, 9, 9, 8, 7, 5, 2, 7, 9, 6,
        5, 1, 6, 7, 3, 0, 3, 3, 6, 9, 5, 4, 9, 3, 2, 5, 7, 2, 9, 1};

    return pisano[n % 60];
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long long n = 10000000000008989ULL;
    std::cout << get_last_digit(n) << "\n";
    return 0;
}

